# Service getting undefined in angular2

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2. I am trying to call the simple service from my component but when I try to call it I am getting  service instance as undefined:

[image: please find the image path below for reference]

Here is my code:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
   <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>


    <script>
    System.config({
      // we want to import modules without writing .js at the end
      defaultJSExtensions: true,
      // the app will need the following dependencies
      map: {
        'angular2': 'node_modules/angular2',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',

      }
    });
    // and to finish, let's boot the app!
    System.import('built/bootstrap');
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
  </body>

</html>
```

**DataService**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Hero }           from './hero';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()

export class DataService{

    getData(){
    return "Hi I am a service response";
    }
}
```

**Appcomponant.ts**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
 import './rxjs-operators';
 import { HeroService } from './toh/hero.service';
 import { HeroListComponent } from './toh/HeroListComponent';



@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'hero-list.component.html',
  providers:[]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 
constructor (private _dataService: DataService) {}
 ngOnInit() { this.getData(); }

 private getData(){
 this._dataService.getData();
 }

    mode='this is test mode'


}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {HeroComponent} from 'toh/hero-list-component'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroService } from './toh/hero.service';
import { DataService } from './toh/DataService';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,

  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent],
  providers:[DataService]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I also tried to add the provider in both appcomponant.ts and app.module.ts but I am getting the error. Please find the image url mention below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, please try to edit your post so that we can have a better link to the error image.
Also, several points are missing to help you properly : The code corresponding to your @NgModule.
Another advice : You should separate the SystemJS config in a separate file instead of putting it into the index.html, but that is up to you.

Hint : You have 2 problems : One with your modules, because the files are not found, and this is most probably coming from missing npm modules or systemJS config, the second one most probably from the service not being declared in the NgModule

Comment: any suggestions on above problem statement, Thanks Brain for editing the code:)

Answer (score 0):

In Appcomponant.ts, you are injecting dataService as a dependency but you have not imported it. You must call

```
import { DataService } from './toh/DataService'
```

in order to inject it as a dependency in your constructor.